# RuntimeExecutionException: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 13: ERROR Places API

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I am getting the following exception while trying out google places API to get likelihood places for [Current Place](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/current-place) in android.

```
Process: me.nabeelkottol.linkedinplaces, PID: 2995
 com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: 
 com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 13: ERROR
 at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn.getResult(Unknown Source)
 at 
 me.nabeelkottol.linkedinplaces.MainActivity$1.onComplete(MainActivity.java:71)
 at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzf.run(Unknown Source)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 13: ERROR
 at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzb.zzz(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbk.zzaa(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbl.zzs(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzs.zzc(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzs.setResult(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.android.gms.location.places.zzm.zzao(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.android.gms.location.places.internal.zzx.onTransact(Unknown Source)
 at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
```

this is my code:

```
try {
      Task<PlaceLikelihoodBufferResponse> placeResult = mPlaceDetectionClient.getCurrentPlace(null);
      placeResult.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<PlaceLikelihoodBufferResponse>() {
        @Override public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<PlaceLikelihoodBufferResponse> task) {

          PlaceLikelihoodBufferResponse likelyPlaces = task.getResult();
          for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces) {
            Log.i(TAG,
                String.format("Place '%s' has likelihood: %g", placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName(),
                    placeLikelihood.getLikelihood()));
          }
          likelyPlaces.release();

        }
      });
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here the line `PlaceLikelihoodBufferResponse likelyPlaces = task.getResult();` is giving me the error.

I have created an `API key` for the android app by giving the package name and SHA-1 key for debug from `Google API console`. And `enabled Google Places API for android` in the `libraries` section. still its giving the same error. Dont know what is wrong with the implementation. Please help me.

There is an [issue](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/issues/73#issuecomment-343696856) reported in github regarding this.

This is my `app/build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "me.nabeelkottol.linkedinplaces"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.6.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

This is my `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="me.nabeelkottol.linkedinplaces">

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

  <application
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:supportsRtl="true"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="My API Key here"/>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: can you please post your build.gradle file.

Comment: @Dilip updated. pls check

Comment: have you added `API` key in your `manifest` file?

Comment: Ya I have added that in question. please see.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add the below code in manifest

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky what exactly are you getting in logcat window

Comment: @UmarAta This issue `com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 13` is device specific. Your code does not fix the issue

Comment: Yes, I have and it does not fix the issue @UmarAta

Comment: can you describe what you did till now and what error you are getting in logcat @Vicky

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue, I was able to resolve it by enabling Google places Api from Google console and adding places api key. As soon as you enable the Places api, it will automatically ask you to add api key, just follow the instructions.

Then add the API key in your manifest file.

```
<application
    ...

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="YOUR_API_KEY" />

</application>
```

Also, your emulator should have latest Google Play Services installed. Else use real Android device for testing.

Comment: Previously I had set my key as indicated here, then suddenly the search function stopped working (it may have had to do with my switching from the AutoCompleteActivity widget to the programmatic [PlacesAutocompleteAdapter](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places/tree/master/PlaceCompleteAdapter). So I had to recreate/obtain a new GCP key

Answer (score 5):

You can see a discussion [here](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/issues/73#issuecomment-346543288) about this issue. For me the problem occurred on the emulator but it was working on a physical device.

Answer (score 3):

OK. I hope you didn't have to waste as much time as I did to find out this. But to get @Umar Ata 's answer working you need to put in both of the meta-data tags in your manifest file. So it should go like this.

```
<application>
...
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="PASTE_YOUR_API_KEY_HERE" />
...    
</application>
```

And even after getting everything right it gave me error:
PLACES_API_ACCESS_NOT_CONFIGURED 9003
which I got fixed by enabling Places SDK for Android and things finally got well.

[image: After enabling Places API enable other additional APIs from inside the APIs tab.]

Comment: Can you please clarify how to enable Place SDK for Android? When enabling APIs and querying for "Place SDK for Android", Google returns only "Places API", which keeps giving me the PLACES_API_ACCESS_NOT_CONFIGURED 9003 error. Thanks

Comment: @user1823280 after enabling Places API. Go to APIs tab from left navigation pane. Over there u can enable and disable certain other Additional APIs. Enable Places SDK for Android from there. I will add a screenshot in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had tried that, but the website returns the following error: "You do not have sufficient permissions to view this page.

Tracking Number: 61..............82"
This only happens when clicking on the "Places SDK for Android" APIs. Can I ask you if it works for you at the time of writing?

Comment: It seems that this occurs for everyone now, here the same question has been asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54519374/problem-to-enable-places-sdk-for-android-google

Comment: Yeah it does. I currently running on my app on Google Play Store.

Comment: The app is SmartRinger. Check it out here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.muhammadtaha.smartringer
Are u sure u are signed in with an appropriate Google account and all the required stuff. AdMob did not let me sign up until I was 18. And if it has been moved or something then why is it showing to me. I just checked it to answer ur question.

Comment: I meant if it worked for you the creation of a new key with the "Places SDK for Android". I checked, and it is not possible anymore for anyone. Your app is working because it is using the "old" SDK (Places SDK for Android) and a key created before 29th of January 2019. The creation of a new key after such a date is now only possible if associated with the new Places SDK, that is, using the new dependency 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0'. Source: developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration

Answer (score 1):

Please try following hope so it will be working.

1) please updated your  \sdk\extras\google\google_play_services and try again.

2)If you are use proguard  please excluded google classes from obfuscating like this in proguard-rules.pro:

```
-keep public class com.google.** {*;}
```

3) Versions of play-services libs should be equal, for example:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.6.0'
```

4)I just had this issue but solved it by downgrading the gradle version like so:

Old, troublesome version:

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-rc2'
```

Fixed version:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
```

and don't forget to add following dependency in project level gradle file.

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

    }
```

Comment: Its a sample and I am running in debug mode without proguard. And I am using this gradle version `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0`

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced this exception when location settings were turned off. Before making the API call please make sure that you have turned on the location services.

Comment: got the solution. see @Umar's answer.

Comment: If location services are turned off you will experience the same error. So just keep that in mind

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have added the following meta-data in your manifest file.

```
<application
    ...

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="YOUR_API_KEY" />

</application>
```

Also check for any API restrictions in your Google API console. If you have enabled any API restriction to the API_KEY, then it will work only for the particular API. You have to add `Places SDK for Android` under API restrictions.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just resolved this error by fixing my permissions on device.  I had requested ALLOW_FINE_LOCATION when I was supposed to request ALLOW_BACKGROUND_LOCATION.  Just thought I would drop this in here so that people are aware that it's possible that this error has nothing to do with your API key.  "Exception 13" appears to be a catch-all of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

Well in my case both `com.google.android.gms.version` and `com.google.android.geo.API_KEY` were already added in manifest.
Why this error occurred because i switched my project into a new system the sha1 key didn't matched from the list.

What i did to resolve this error is:
I have generated new SHA1 from my new system and added this SHA1 in under

> credentials=> API Key=> then Add package name and SHA1

of **Places SDK for Android**