# i have followed all the steps for google places API still giving below exception:

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

```
 03-05 15:47:47.015 20062-20062/com.electivechaos.checklist E/ContentValues: Exception: %s
     com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 13: ERROR
     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzb.zzy(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbk.zzz(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbl.zzr(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BasePendingResult.zzc(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BasePendingResult.setResult(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.location.places.zzm.zzao(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.location.places.internal.zzx.onTransact(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565)
```

My manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyCA-2HMYGs_AiUC3cvCDw49o2AuHkp5A40"/>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RuntimeExecutionException: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 13: ERROR Places API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47279161/runtimeexecutionexception-com-google-android-gms-common-api-apiexception-13-e)

Comment: I have added play services version too.

Comment: and what about `com.google.android.geo.API_KEY`

Comment: Yes I added both , I have posted my manifest in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identified. I was doing wrong here :
 `android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"`

replaced with

`"android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"`

Answer (score 1):

After so many attempts, it finally worked when I run on a real device. My emulators had Google Play Services installed and I was still getting an exception.

Make sure to test on a real device.