# Problem to enable Places SDK for Android (google)

Tags: android, api, google-maps, sdk, google-places-api

Please help,

When I Click Places SDK For android to access the page for enable it appears this :
You do not have sufficient permissions to view this page.
Tracking Number: 4169288790274014457

Whats the problem? what should i do to enable this API?

Thank You

Comment: The issue has been reported in the issue tracker, you may star the [issue #123835103](https://issuetracker.google.com/123835103) to get updates regarding the progress of the issue.

Comment: I got the same issue. I cannot enable Google Places for Android SDK in the API console. 
Also Places SDK for Android disappeared from the API library list.
https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library?project=digital-pagoda-154303&folder&organizationId

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to enable Places SDKs. Either you already had them enabled and you can continue to use them for 6 months, or you only need to enable Places API (which integrates new Places SDKs from now on).

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/maps-platform/introducing-new-improved-places-sdks

For using new Places SDKs now you only need to enable Places API. Don't forget to restrict your API keys to your mobile apps.

Answer (score 0):

Google Place SDK for Android is deprecated and migrated guides are available in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31449649/android-google-places-api-getautocompletepredictions-returns-status-places-api/54567092#54567092).

Answer (score 0):

Login with authorised account Go to side menu - Select IAM & Admin , select IAM
now select your project from Top-left and go to library and enable the Respective api