# Google place api for android not getting enable

Tags: android, google-places-api

I have to enable google place API for Android, but unfortunately, I am not 
able to enable google place API for Android on Google developer console.

I getting the following message

> You do not have sufficient permissions to view this page.
>   Tracking Number: 529859675235296356

Here I have attached screenshots:

[image: getting this kind of message]

This what I have tried earlier:
[Problem to enable Places SDK for Android (google)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54519374/problem-to-enable-places-sdk-for-android-google)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the post says, if you haven't enabled the Places SDK for iOS/Android before, you won't be able to do it now. Places API now integrates these services and you just need to enable Places API.

Have a look at this link for more help:
https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration#find-ac-prediction