# Google throws the PLACES_API_ACCESS_NOT_CONFIGURED even if i enabled the Google places API?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, geocoding, google-places

I have used my app in google places API even if I configured google places API (Refer the screenshot)everything but still google throws the following error 
**com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 9003: PLACES_API_ACCESS_NOT_CONFIGURED**

Anybody facing these kinds of issues? for last 20 days only I'm getting these kinds of error before that the same function working fine. Any solution for this?

Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67Kac.png)

Comment: Can you verify that your api key is still correct and that you don't have any billing issues?

Comment: Yes is that correct key, no issues in the billing account and I have the places API quota in unlimited too @JensV

Comment: @JensV please check the link https://i.imgur.com/qW51kZV.png

Comment: Can you check the answers from this question if anything solves it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47279161/runtimeexecutionexception-com-google-android-gms-common-api-apiexception-13-e

Comment: @JensV i already tried this one, let me check once again. thanks for the share man

Comment: Have you migrated to the new Places SDK?

Comment: @ShawnDomingo yes integrated new places and the issue solved!